# How to work on SAS Data

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on SAS from the past 5 years and I am aware of only Base SAS ,SAS macro and Proc SQL and no other languages. Recently management has decided to migrate all the SAS code into python and they wanted us to learn PYTHON and convert all SAS codes into PYTHON(Thanks to Management). I am very much confused how to get started on this, I have read through some python online materials  but I am wondering how to convert all the SAS code into python. To get started Can you please help me on the below sample SAS code how do we convert this in Python,

Please assume I have sample raw_data as following,

```
Name Age Val
Abc  23 100
Pqr  24 200
Xyz  26 400
```

I have below code which is the starting ,

```
   %if %sysfunc(exist(raw_data)) eq 0 %then %do;
    Data old_data;
     set raw_data(where age>=24);
    run;
   %end;

  proc sort data=olddata out=newdata;
  by name descending val;
  run;
```

Thanks in advance for your Help,

Regards,
Surya...

Comment: Correction :%if %sysfunc(exist(raw_data)) eq 1 then %do;

Comment: You're going to have to learn Python.  Asking people to help you with converting a snippet won't help you get where you need to be.  Has your management considered R as a SAS alternative?  They should.

Comment: You've asked the same question twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667451/how-to-convert-sas-code-into-python-code